# Purpose of $ in Symbolic Link?

Tags: symlink

I am following [a procedure](http://www.codepool.biz/raspberrypi-barcode-scanner-webcam-python.html) that indicates creating a symbolic link:

```
sudo ln -s $(DynamsoftBarcodeReader)/lib/libDynamsoftBarcodeReader.so /usr/lib/libDynamsoftBarcodeReader.so
```

I am interpreting this to mean that I need to implement:

```
sudo ln -s /home/pi/Desktop/dbr/lib/libDynamsoftBarcodeReader.so /usr/lib/libDynamsoftBarcodeReader.so
```

My question / concern is the $ in the procedure: what is its purpose?  Attempts to Google were not successful

[image]

Comment: Why a screenshot instead of copying the output?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you're meant to type this in a shell, this is a [command substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_substitution). The shell executes the command `DynamsoftBarcodeReader` and replaces `$(DynamsoftBarcodeReader)` in that command line by the output obtained by running `DynamsoftBarcodeReader`. For example, if the command `DynamsoftBarcodeReader` prints `/home/pi/Desktop/dbr`, then the target of the symlink will be `/home/pi/Desktop/dbr/lib/libDynamsoftBarcodeReader.so`.

Note to future visitors: in a makefile, the syntax `$(…)` has a different meaning: it takes the value of a variable. This tutorial doesn't mention makefiles anywhere, so presumably the command is intended to be typed on the command line, in a shell such as bash, and there it's a command substitution.

If the `$` was actually in a symbolic link, it would have no special meaning, the symlink would just be pointing to a target that happens to contain the character `$`. But that's not happening here.

Comment: Given the context and the posted screenshot, have I correctly created the symbolic link?  Thanks for introducing command substitution

Comment: @gatorback I don't know. You have created a symlink, and it makes sense, but I don't know that software, so I can't be sure that it's the right link.